# How to measure background activerecord model performance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, benchmarking, performance-testing, sidekiq

I seem to have a very slow method in one of my models, and I'm learning about how to fix it. Along with that comes benchmarking it effectively, and I don't think I'm doing that very well at the moment.

The model runs in the background in sidekiq, processing anchor text against keywords to find a matches. I've been using the MethodProfiler gem along with timestamps to narrow slowness down to my `get_top_match` method. My code looks like this:

```
# This is the code I'm running in the background
def spam_check
  words.each do |word|
    spam_keyword = SpamKeyword.top_match_for(word)
    spam_keyword.spam_score
  end
end

class SpamKeyword

def self.top_match_for(anchor_text)
    all_keywords_set.find do |keyword|
        if Regexp.new(keyword.keyword) =~ anchor_text
            if keyword.only_match_whole_words
                if /#{keyword.keyword}\b/ =~ anchor_text || /#{keyword.keyword.pluralize}\b/ =~ anchor_text
                    return keyword
                end
            else
                return keyword
            end
        end
    end
end

def self.all_keywords_set
    order(spam_score: :desc)
end

#The ways I've found to benchmark so far:`

MethodProfiler results for: SpamKeyword
+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Method            | Min Time   | Max Time     | Average Time | Total Time      | Total Calls |
+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| .top_match_for    | 100.142 ms | 11406.057 ms | 2854.346 ms  | 19657882.947 ms | 6887        |
| .all_keywords_set | 0.056 ms   | 1318.212 ms  | 1.762 ms     | 12159.412 ms    | 6899        |
+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+

spam_check_time 1273.384929213
    num_words_processed 222
    secs_per_word 5.735968149608109
```

I'd love more tips on how to improve performance, but I think what's probably going to be most useful down the line, and useful to future readers of this question, is what are the best ways to see into the stack trace and database calls for background methods like these?

Answer (score 1):

I think best tool here would be [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof).

It can show the overall time spent in each method. In addition, it will also show which methods call the current method and which methods its calls. [Here is example output with comments](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof/blob/master/examples/graph.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Basically for today, the most relevant tool for performance measurement is [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips), you should definitely use it.